# C code truncating to 7 bits max value

Tags: c, matlab, casting

I have some code that I am trying to use for network communications to pull information from c++ to MATLAB. I am using the pnet program (mex file from c) from the Mathworks open exchange: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345-tcp-udp-ip-toolbox-2-0-6?s_tid=answers_rc2-2_p5_MLT

On my receive end I am expecting to receive int8's, which I then typecast as uint8's. As such, for each received byte I would expect 0-255 as the value.

I noticed some discrepancies where I was receiving lots of 127s on my receive end, and found out by doing some basic debugging that for every value I send from 128-255, my receive code (immediately after the pnet receive call) is displaying 127.

Thus, I believe something may be buggy in the pnet.c file causing the values to truncate to the 7-bit max value rather than displaying the full `uint8` range.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening? I am primarily a matlab user and don't spend much time in data typecasting, so I feel a little out of my depth here.

Receive code that returns bad/funny error character:

```
data = pnet('read',number of bytes to read,'noblock')
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't happen in the transmitting end?

Comment: Show us your MATLAB code that uses the library please.

Comment: If you "cast" `int8 -1` into a `uint8`, does MATLAB do it like C and give you 255 or does it do some strange truncation?

Comment: @4386427 I have access to the transmitting side bytes as well - so I can inspect them to know what I'm sending across the UDP socket

Comment: @AndreKampling I am on a different box currently with no access to that code piece. I will attempt to transfer it later

Comment: @NickT Every instance of casting I have done in MATLAB has given the expected return value - for instance, if I say four bytes should be a uint32, ex. newVar = typecast(int8(data(1:4)),'uint32') it concatenates them correctly (assuming all of those bytes are in the range 0-127).

Comment: Can you look at the data right from the library before you do anything? That would at least isolate the problem to your code or the library (or how it's config'd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening here. It turns out that if you are receiving values greater than 127 into MATLAB using UDP sockets (Java/MATLAB UDP implementation force-casts int8's) and don't specify the type of data you are expecting to receive, MATLAB will assume some non-descript error character. If you further try to typecast that error character, it will clamp to the highest value possible for that type.

In my case because I was getting some data back correctly I did not realize that I wasn't correctly instructing MATLAB to receive as uint8's. Thus, it was receiving correctly for 0-127, but giving me the error character for 128-255. I then tried typecasting that error character into multiple types and found that for each cast it was displaying as the max value for that specific type.

The fix only required me to add a 'uint8' option to my socket receive call.

Fixed code:

```
data = pnet('read',number of bytes,'uint8','noblock')
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a fix.  I'll remove my answer then.

Comment: Adding code in your question (not working) and here in your answer (working) would help other people that might have this problem too. Also think of [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) to show a wider community that the problem is solved.